# How to dual-doot with BBS (BIOS Boot Specification)?

Tags: boot, pop-os, refind

I recently brought a Samsung 870 EVO 2TB drive to dual boot with.

When I installed Windows 10, I discovered that (to boot Windows automatically), I have to set this drive to the top of my BBS (BIOS Boot Specification) priorities list (a list which only shows the names of my SSD and HDD - which I only use for storing files).

However, I want to dual boot Windows 10 with Pop OS using rEFInd (with Windows and Pop OS installed to separate partitions on the Samsung Drive). Is it possible to do this with BBS, and how do I control the boot priority list of this when dual booting?

My motherboard is an ASUS H310M-K R2.0.

Comment: You need to understand 1. your motherboard is new so it has UEFI, not BIOS; 2. All OSes should be installed in UEFI mode and 3. that mode requirements, namely an ESP (EFI System Partition) that should have been created already by the Windows installer. This ESP is where ALL your bootloaders reside irrespective of where the OSes are actually installed. Until you understand this you shouldn't be installing OSes let alone dual-booting.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I have fixed the issue.  My CSM was misconfigured by my system integrator.  This issue has now been resolved (by disabling CSM altogether, removing all partitions on the drive and reinstalling Windows), and I will be dual-booting in dual course.

Comment: CSM should be disabled indeed in order to avoid mistakes like booting installation/live media in Legacy/CSM mode.